# PHP - preg_match and "Unknown modifier" error

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, ereg

I had that test that worked fine :

```
if (ereg("([0-9]{2})[-./]([0-9]{2})[-./]([0-9]{4})[ ]([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})", $dateToTest, $tab) == false)
```

and as ereg is deprecated, I have replaced that test with this one :

```
if (preg_match("/([0-9]{2})[-./]([0-9]{2})[-./]([0-9]{4})[ ]([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})/", $dateToTest, $tab) == false)
```

But I get the following error :

```
Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '.' in ..................
```

What is the problem and how may I solve it ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is the delimiter `/` because you use it in your regexp again.

You have to escape it `\/` or use another delimiter like `@`:

```
if (preg_match("@([0-9]{2})[-/.]([0-9]{2})[-/.]([0-9]{4})[ ]([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})@", $dateToTest, $tab) == false)
```

See the example #3 in the [Docu](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php). There is also a manual about [delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).

Comment: I added a link to the docu about delimiters.

Answer (score 4):

You have unescaped slashes in the expression.  Either change `/` to `\/` or use a different delimiter such as  `@` to start the expression.

Answer (score 0):

the error is here `/.`. i don't know what do you mean by this regexp, so you can change it to `.` or `\.`

Comment: That seems evident : I test a date-time format, that can have 3 separators for the date : [- . /]

Comment: @Oliver oh, sorry. it's the end of my working day :)